# Scheme leibniz series

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong in my math.

```
(define (make-pi tolerance)
  (let loop ((n 0)
             (prev +nan.0)
             (curr 0.0))
    (if (< (abs (- curr prev)) tolerance)
        (* 4.0 curr)
        (loop (add1 n)
              curr
              ((if (even? n) + -) curr (/ 1.0 (add1 (+ n n))))))))
```

The output must be:

```
(make-pi 0.1) =>  3.09162380666784
(make-pi 0.001) =>  3.1410926536210413
(make-pi 0.0000001) => 3.141592603589817
```

But I keep getting:

```
(make-pi 0.1) =>  2.9760461760461765
(make-pi 0.001) =>  3.143588659585789
(make-pi 0.0000001) => 3.1415928535897395
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your tolerance test. You're testing the tolerance and then multiplying by 4. Do it the other way around (and return prev instead of curr) and you get what you seem to expect:

```
(define (make-pi tolerance)
  (let loop ([n 0]
             [prev +nan.0]
             [curr 0.0])
    (if (< (abs (- curr prev)) (/ tolerance 4))
        (* 4 prev)
        (loop (add1 n)
              curr
              ((if (even? n) + -) curr (/ 1 (+ 1 n n)))))))

> (make-pi 0.1)
3.09162380666784
> (make-pi 0.001)
3.1410926536210413
> (make-pi 0.0000001)
3.141592603589817
```